# AngularFire Offline: queryFn is not a function

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2-offline

Im trying to retrieve chats from a firebase database with AngularFire Offline. To achieve this I wrote this function:

```
  getChat(chatId: string, batch, lastTimestamp?) {
    let query = {
      orderByChild: 'timestamp',
      limitToLast: batch
    }
    if(lastTimestamp) query['startAt'] = lastTimestamp;

    return this.afo.list('Chats/' + chatId, {query: query})
  }
```

But when I'm trying to run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: queryFn is not a function
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Im using:

- "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6"
- "angularfire2-offline": "^4.3.1"

Thanks in advance!